# python:cant figure out whats wrong in this code but still i am getting an taberror

Tags: python, indentation

getting an error in line 28 having if count<10 : ^ 
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.

count= input('Give me no. of donuts: ') if count<10 : print('No. of donuts: %s' % (count)) 
else : print('No. of donuts:Many')

return

to see how i exactly wrote it, follow the link given
http://pzy.be/v/1321/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Please format your code as it appears in your editor, interpreter. This error is related to the way you wrote your code - so we need to see it exactly to be able to help you.

Comment: It says exactly what's wrong, and means exactly what it says.

Comment: Please - no one edit his question, the OP needs to format it because only he knows how his erroneous code is supposed to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed tabs with spaces while indenting your code. [Don't do that](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Comment: He has *definitely* mixed them.

Answer (score 3):

How about reading the error message:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix tabs and spaces in Python, because how many spaces a tab counts as is dependent upon what program and what settings you are viewing it in. Whitespace, and in particular how indented a line of code is, is very important in Python as it determines flow control and many other things. So all people must see the same code.'

For example, these are different in Python:

```
if a:
    b()
c()
```

-

```
if a:
    b()
    c()
```